# 'zsh: killed : conda' after adding it to path

Tags: macos, conda, zsh, apple-m1, mini-forge

I am new to Mac, and I have just installed miniforge from [conda-forge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge) and then added the following line to my .zshrc file in the home directory.

```
export PATH=“/Users/myusername/miniforge3/bin:$PATH”
```

After this, every time I open the terminal and type 'conda', I only get
`zsh: killed: conda`

Why does this happen? Could someone please help me?

Edit:
On running `bash conda`, I get the following errors:

```
/Users/myusername/miniforge3/bin/conda: conda: line 3: import: command not found
/Users/myusername/miniforge3/bin/conda: conda: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `sys. argv'
/Users/myusername/miniforge3/bin/conda: conda: line 6: `if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1].startswith('shell.') and sys.path and sys.path[0] == '':'
```

Any idea how I can get rid of this?

Comment: Use `conda init zsh` - don't manipulate PATH manually. Ping me if there is still and issue and I will reopen.

Comment: ```conda init zsh``` still gives ```zsh: killed conda init zsh``` . Any other idea?

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue. Did you find a solution?